# How change the jquery position on screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the html file top I have included the css file and javascript:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="carousel.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vertical_slider.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="glow-effect.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.caroufredsel/6.1.0/jquery.carouFredSel.packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.carousel.js"></script>
        <script src="java_script.js"></script>
```

The jquery is thee cycle2
The jquery is working also the second one the caroufredsel both are working.

But i want to move the cycle2 to the left so it will be on the left side of the caroufredsel.
In the html bottom inside the body I have:

```
<div class="vertical-slider-container">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" id="prev1" class="vertical-slider-nav vertical-slider-nav-up" />
    <div class="slideshow"
         data-cycle-fx="carousel"
         data-cycle-timeout="3000"
         data-cycle-next="#next1"
         data-cycle-prev="#prev1"
         data-cycle-carousel-visible="3"
         data-cycle-carousel-vertical="true">

        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach1.jpg" />
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach2.jpg" />
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach3.jpg" />
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach4.jpg" />
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach5.jpg" />
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach9.jpg" />
    </div>
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" id="next1" class="vertical-slider-nav vertical-slider-nav-down" />
</div>
```

And the cycle2 css file content:

```
.vertical-slider-container {
    background: #fff;
    border: 20px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    margin: 40px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
}

.slideshow {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.slideshow img {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.vertical-slider-nav {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 40px;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.vertical-slider-nav-up {
    top: -60px;
}

.vertical-slider-container:hover .vertical-slider-nav-up:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.vertical-slider-container:hover .vertical-slider-nav-up {
    top: -20px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.vertical-slider-nav-down {
    bottom: -60px;
}

.vertical-slider-container:hover .vertical-slider-nav-down:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.vertical-slider-container:hover .vertical-slider-nav-down {
    bottom: -20px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}![enter image description here][1]
```

I tried to change values of many properties in the css code but it didn't effect anything.

EDIT

What I mean is that I have one jquery already in the middle.
I want to move the cycle2 a bit to the left so it will be on the left side of the other big image.
This is edited screenshot I did I took the cycle2 from the center and pasted it where I want it to be.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move the cycle 2 to the left by applying float:left to .vertical-slider-container class

```
   .vertical-slider-container {
      background: #fff;
      border: 20px solid #fff;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      margin-top: 40px;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
      width: 120px;
   }
```

Comment: That move it to the far left. I updated my question with a link for a screenshot of what i mean.

Comment: well if you want to place it little left then add margin-left: 20px; below margin-top: 40px; in my above css code

Comment: I changed the position to absolute and added left and top. left 290px and top 80px and it's working as i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to move all the things to left a bit?
If so, Just update the container margin a little bit.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/uzLt6d4x/1/)

```
.vertical-slider-container {
    background: #fff;
    border: 20px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    margin: 40px;
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
}
```

I'm not sure i understand your question clearly. Hope it helps!

Comment: huan edited my question a bit explaining what i mean with a screenshot of what i mean. Moving the auto from the margin make it moving to positions i didn't mean.

Comment: Sorry i am not a CSS expert, and it's not simple as i thought before, hope someone can help you on this :)

Answer (score 0):

The `top`, `left`, `bottom`, and `right` CSS properties are not available when an element is statically positioned. Static positioning is the default, and the position is automatic. Try adding the attribute `position: relative` to each of those elements you are trying to move.